# Should we exclude target variable from DFS in featuretools?

Tags: featuretools

While passing the dataframes as entities in an entityset and use DFS on that, are we supposed to exclude target variable from the DFS? I have a model that had 0.76 roc_auc score after traditional feature selection methods tried manually and used feature tools to see if it improves the score. So used DFS on entityset that included target variable as well. Surprisingly, the roc_auc score went up to 0.996 and accuracy to 0.9997 and so i am doubtful of the scores as i passed target variable as well into Deep Feature Synthesis and there the infor related to the target might have been leaked to the training? Am i assuming correct?

Answer (score 8):

Deep Feature Synthesis and Featuretools do allow you to keep your target in your entity set (in order to create new features using historical values of it), but you need to set up the “time index” and use “cutoff times” to do this without label leakage.

You use the time index to specify the column that holds the value for when data in each row became known. This column is specified using the `time_index` keyword argument when creating the entity using `entity_from_dataframe`.

Then, you use cutoff times when running `ft.dfs()` or `ft.calculate_feature_matrix()` to specify the last point in time you should use data when calculating each row of your feature matrix. Feature calculation will only use data up to and including the cutoff time. So, if this cutoff time is before the time index value of your target, you won’t have label leakage.

You can read about those concepts in detail in the documentation on [Handling Time](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/getting_started/handling_time.html).

If you don’t want to deal with the target at all you can

1. You can use pandas to drop it out of your dataframe entirely before making it an entity. If it’s not in the entityset, it can’t be used to create features.
2. You can set the `drop_contains` keyword argument in `ft.dfs`  to `['target']`. This stops any feature from being created which includes the string `'target'`.

No matter which of the above options you do, it is still possible to pass a target column directly through DFS. If you add the target to your cutoff times dataframe it is passed through to the resulting feature matrix. That can be useful because it ensures the target column remains aligned with the other features. You can an example of passing the label through [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html?highlight=label#running-dfs-with-cutoff-times)  in the documentation.

**Advanced Solution using Secondary Time Index**

Sometimes a single time index isn’t enough to represent datasets where information in a row became known at two different times. This commonly occurs when the target is a column. To handle this situation, we need to use a “secondary time index”.

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/sjrothsc/using-featuretools-for-missed-appointments) is an example from a Kaggle kernel on predicting when a patient will miss an appointment with a doctor where a secondary time index is used. The dataset has a `scheduled_time`, when the appointment is scheduled, and an `appointment_day`, which is when the appointment actually happens. We want to tell Featuretools that some information like the patient’s age is known when they schedule the appointment, but other information like whether or not a patient actually showed up isn't known until the day of the appointment.

To do this, we create an `appointments` entity with a secondary time index as follows:

```
es = ft.EntitySet('Appointments')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="appointments",
                              dataframe=data,
                              index='appointment_id',
                              time_index='scheduled_time',
                              secondary_time_index={'appointment_day': ['no_show', 'sms_received']})
```

This says that most columns can be used at the time index `scheduled_time`, but that the variables `no_show` and `sms_received` can’t be used until the value in secondary time index.

We then make predictions at the `scheduled_time` by setting our cutoff times to be

```
cutoff_times = es['appointments'].df[['appointment_id', 'scheduled_time', 'no_show']]
```

By passing that dataframe into DFS, the `no_show` column will be passed through untouched, but while historical values of `no_show` can still be used to create features. An example would be something like `ages.PERCENT_TRUE(appointments.no_show)` or “the percentage of people of each age that have not shown up in the past”.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer a hundred-and-one times for this invaluable information!

Answer (score -4):

If you are using the target variable in your DFS, than you are leaking information about it in your training data. So you have to remove your target variable while you are doing every kind of feature engineering (manuall or via DFS).

Comment: this is not entirely correct. Please see Max’s answer for all the nuances involved. The concept of cutoff time is particularly prudent. In many cases, you can use the values of the target variable from previous points in time.